# É uma má prática verificar Auth nos components que quero travar?

Tags: angular, autenticação

Eu tenho a seguinte logica de autenticação

```
 initAuthListener() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
        if (user) {
            this.store.dispatch(new Auth.SetAuthenticated());
            this.router.navigate(['/training']);
        } else {
            this.trainingServices.cancelSubscriptions();
                this.store.dispatch(new Auth.SetUnauthenticated());
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
    });
}
```

Como o app.component estava

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
this.authService.initAuthListener();
                 }
```

Toda primeira chamada na pagina ia para /login, então eu passei a verificação para o training.component, que é onde precisa ter autorização.

É uma pratica ruim? Qual seria minha alternativa?

---

Eu modifiquei da seguinte maneira, aparentemente está ok:

```
initAuthListener() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
        if (user) {
            this.store.dispatch(new Auth.SetAuthenticated());
            this.router.navigate(['/training']);
        } else {
             if((this.ROTAS_LIBERADAS.includes(this.router.url))){
                    this.trainingServices.cancelSubscriptions();
                    this.store.dispatch(new Auth.SetUnauthenticated());
                }else{
                    this.trainingServices.cancelSubscriptions();
                    this.store.dispatch(new Auth.SetUnauthenticated());
                    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: melhor vc usar um router guard https://angular.io/guide/router#canload-guard-guarding-unauthorized-loading-of-feature-modules Se não vc teria que duplicar essa lógica em todo componente que precisa de autenticação

Comment: @EduardoVargas obrigado pela dica, vou dar uma lida na doc que você me passou. Eu olhei por alto e parece que é o que estou usando, mas posso estar enganado.

Comment: então respondendo sobre a má pratica eu fazia isso antes, preferi salva um token no cokkies e depois conferir ele no middle do backend axo que desgasta menos o servidor, imagina a cada click vc ter que fazer uma requisição

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pratica que uso é a descrita na doc do angular usando uma service com um metodo chamado CanActived e colocando a validação nas rotas.

Exemplo:

**auth-guard.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardService {

  private isAuthenticated: boolean = true;
  constructor() { }

  canActivate() {
    return this.isAuthenticated;
  }

  login(){
    return this.isAuthenticated = !this.isAuthenticated
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [

  ],
  imports: [

    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'login' , component: LoginComponent },

      { path: 'welcome', canActivate: [AuthGuardService], component: WelcomeComponent }

    ])
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuardService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Eu voltei ao padrão. Na implementação do canActivate e canLoad em auth-service eu fiz a lógica que eu precisava. Verificando se a rota é liberada caso não esteja logado e verificando a Role caso logado.

Comment: Boa! É bem melhor seguir os padroes pois fica mais facil dar manutençao

Comment: Esqueci de agradecer :D Obrigado  :)